# UITableView Load more autosrolling issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation

Folks,

I am getting a weird issue while applying **scroll to load more** to my `UITableView`. I added a ***YouTube*** video also for reference. At scrolling to bottom, API hits server and gets next 5 records. At this time I am not reloading the table, neither I want too. I am simply adding more rows to the table. The code is below:

```
// adding new rows rather than reloading the table
if(loadMore)
{
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < arr.count; i++)
    {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arr.count+i inSection:0]]; // adding max 5 new indexPaths
    }

    [self.tblData beginUpdates];
    [self.tblData insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; // insert with fade animation
    [arrData addObjectsFromArray:arr]; // adding new data to existing array
    [self.tblData endUpdates];
}
```

Now see the video I uploaded. On 1st load more it works like charm. You can see it at [00:07](https://youtu.be/Cxz-2dJvPXI?t=07). It adds 5 more rows at the bottom with fade animation.

But after 1st load more, for next 5 load more it brings 5 more records from the server and adds them to the table but also it autoscrolls at the same index, see video at [00:15](https://youtu.be/Cxz-2dJvPXI?t=15), [00:23](https://youtu.be/Cxz-2dJvPXI?t=23), [00:30](https://youtu.be/Cxz-2dJvPXI?t=30) an so on.

You can see it works good on 1st load more (at [00:07](https://youtu.be/Cxz-2dJvPXI?t=07)), but never after that even all the records are coming good.

After that I changed simulator animation to **Slow** and you can see that after [01:01](https://youtu.be/Cxz-2dJvPXI?t=61)

Can anyone suggest me why it is happening? Somewhere I found it is due to `AutoLayout`, then i made another storyboard which has disabled `autolayout` but problem still occurs.